# Is there a next/Link function to pass query string to another Link

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm using nextjs.
I'm opening `host.domain/PageA?param1=one&param2=two`. On this page I've got a next/Link object to `host.domain/PageB`

is there an easier way to pass this parameters to to PageB than:

```
<Link href={`/PageB?param1=${Router.query.param1}&param2=${Router.query.param2}`} />
```

something like

```
<Link passQueryString />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no native way to do that using Next.js, what you can do is to create a wrapper around `Link` to add that functionality.

```
import NextLink from "next/link";

const Link = ({ passQueryString, href, children, ...otherProps }) => (
  <NextLink href={`${href}?${passQueryString}`} {...otherProps}>
    {children}
  </NextLink>
);

export default () => (
  <div>
    Hello World.{" "}
    <Link href="/about" passQueryString="paramA=b&paramB=c">
      <a>About</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

Also you can use `query-string` library to send an object and then stringify that object.

```
import NextLink from "next/link";
import queryString from "query-string";

const Link = ({ passQueryString, href, children, ...otherProps }) => (
  <NextLink
    href={`${href}?${queryString.stringify(passQueryString)}`}
    {...otherProps}
  >
    {children}
  </NextLink>
);

export default () => (
  <div>
    Hello World.{" "}
    <Link href="/about" passQueryString={{ paramA: "a", paramB: "b" }}>
      <a>About</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-shtern-onos5?file=/pages/index.js)

Answer (score 3):

"Link can also receive an URL object and it will automatically format it to create the URL string"

so you can use instad of `href=""`, this `href={{ pathname, query }}`
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#with-url-object

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Index = () => {

    const router = useRouter()

    return (
        <Link href={{ pathname: '/pageB', query: { ...router.query }}}>
            <a>Test</a>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

or simply

```
//or <Link href={{ pathname: '/pageB', query: { params1: router.query.params1, params2: router.query.par } }}>
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-cache-2tqum?file=/pages/index.js)